# C# Mock - Stripe Services - Returns null

Tags: c#, mocking, stripe-payments, payment

I've got a problem with unit testing Stripe services.

I have a controller, which calls my services and these again call the stripe apis.

I'm trying to mock the CreateAsync Method inside my PaymentIntentService.

*My Service:*

```
   private readonly PaymentIntentService _paymentIntentService;

    #region Constructor


    public StripePaymentIntentService(Stripe.PaymentIntentService paymentIntentService)
    {
        _paymentIntentService = paymentIntentService;
    }

    public async Task<PaymentIntent> CreatePaymentIntentAsync(PaymentIntentCreateRequest request)
    {
        var paymentIntentCreateOptions = new PaymentIntentCreateOptions
        {
            Amount = request.Amount,
            Currency = request.Currency,
            Customer = request.StripeCustomerId,
        };

        if (request.IsHold)
            paymentIntentCreateOptions.CaptureMethod = "manual";

        if (request.IsSetupForFuturePayments)
            paymentIntentCreateOptions.SetupFutureUsage = "off_session";

        //I want to Mock the CreateAsync Method.
        var intent = await _paymentIntentService.CreateAsync(paymentIntentCreateOptions);

        return intent;
    }
```

*My test:*

```
public class StripePaymentIntentServiceShould
{

    #region members
    private Stripe.PaymentIntentCreateOptions request;
    private readonly StripePaymentIntentService _service;
    private readonly Mock<PaymentIntentService> _mockService;
    #endregion

    #region constructor
    public StripePaymentIntentServiceShould()        {

        _mockService  = new Mock<PaymentIntentService>();

        _mockService.Reset();

        request = new Stripe.PaymentIntentCreateOptions()
        {
            Amount = 123,
            Currency = ""
            CaptureMethod = "",
            SetupFutureUsage = "",
            Customer = "",
        };

        _mockService.Setup(service => service.CreateAsync(request, null, default)).Returns(Task.FromResult(new PaymentIntent { Id = "dummy" }));
        _service = new StripePaymentIntentService(_mockService.Object);

  
    }
    #endregion

    #region methods

    [Fact]
    public async void CreatePaymentIntentAsync_Should()
    {
        //Arrange      
        PaymentIntentCreateRequest req = new PaymentIntentCreateRequest()
        {
            Amount = 123,
            Currency = "",
            IsHold = true,
            isSetupForFuturePayments = true,
            StripeCustomerId = "",
        };

        //Act
        var result = await _service.CreatePaymentIntentAsync(req);


        //Assert
        result.Id.Should().Be("dummy");
    }
    #endregion
}
```

But the CreateAsync returns null instead of the PaymentIntent Object.

Could you help me with that?

Thanks

Comment: You setup the mock to expect a specific instance but use a different instance in the test so the mock returns null by default. Use `It.IsAny<>()` to loosen the match and get the desired behavior. Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Comment: Check the status of the response and see if you are getting 200 OK or a 400/500 error code.  The PaymentIntent is in the body of the response and when you get an error there is no body.  This usually indicates your request is bad.  The Error 
Status will help indicate the failure.